# Accepting an offer I initially rejected?

Tags: job-offer, new-job

I am recent graduate and I have gotten a few offers a few days ago. I don't I handle things really well, and here is what happened

1.) Verbally accepted offer from company A 10 minutes after interview ended

2.) Offer from company B same day but few hours later.

3.) spent the rest of day and night deciding.

4.) Verbally accept offer B next morning, wrote decline offer email to company A saying I decided to take another offer with reasons

5.) company A calls me to convince me and tells me to reconsider.

6.) about 4-5 hours later I accepted offer A again

From company A perspective, do you think I am being indecisive and irresponsible? How bad of an impression have I made?

Also does this really matter if I am starting my career at this company?

Comment: Relax. You're fine. You might as well just delete this question.

Answer (score 2):

As a recent graduate, taking time to consider offers (i.e. sleeping on it) is perhaps a lesson well learned from this experience. I wouldn't worry about it at this stage, they did try to call you to convince you to reconsider, so obviously they still want you. Well done for getting a job!

Answer (score 1):

**Don't worry, you did not make a bad impression.**

Of course it would be better in the future to take time to consider your options, but that is really beside the point in this case.  You weren't "indecisive" but changed your mind based on new information:

- **Getting a different job offer before you formalized things would always be a legitimate reason to change your mind.**  Even if you had waited longer to consider the original offer, as would be a good idea, the second offer could have come in right after that, and you would be in the same situation.
- **The company making a case that you should reconsider their offer is also a legitimate reason to change your mind.**  Even if they presented no new information, the fact that they want you enough to call you up and make a case for joining them might be a decisive reason to pick them.

So, what you describe is perfectly defensible and **even a seasoned expert might have plausibly followed the same sequence of events.** This doesn't reflect negatively on you.

Now is a great time to focus on the positive: you are in the enviable position of being in high demand, with two companies wanting you as an employee.  That speaks extremely well of you.

Comment: Since they came back to you, I doubt that they would consider you to be indecisive. If you had called them up a couple days later and said you changed your mind, that would be a different impression. But since they wanted you enough to try to change your mind, I think you are fine.

Answer (score 0):

In hiring it's always a good thing to take time to consider. Even if you're overly enthusiastic about the position. Personally I always tell the hiring person after an interview they'll hear back from me within the week. This way I can negotiate other offers and go through the financial decision making as well (can I live with said salary).

To answer your question more in detail. Every hiring manager will understand your position and your inexperience in the hiring process. Nevertheless it's always wise to be friendly and honest when communicating, even if you change your opinion more than once.

One more point that strikes me is that the company reached out to you again after they have received your refusal. It seems they are not disappointed at all, but extremely interested. They really want you, so if the other company has a better offer in any way, you might propose that to them;

> "I really am in doubt, your company is much more interesting, but the benefits from another offer I received are pulling me away from you. Is there something we can do about (salary or vacation days) to make my decision easier?"

I hope you get the job you feel happiest with. Good luck!